# Not so smoothly sliding down/up and details and thumbnail relate before sliding detail

Tags: jquery, css

Use Bootstrap 3

```
  <div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--/carousel-inner-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-4"></i></a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-4"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--/myCarousel-->
    <!--expanding more details for certain thumbnail clicked.-->
    <div class="details">
    Thumbnail 1
    </div>
    <div class="details">
    Thumbnail 2
    </div>
    <div class="details">
    Thumbnail 3
    </div>
    <div class="details">
    Thumbnail 4
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.details{
  display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function(e){
console.log('here');
$('.details').slideToggle('slow');
$(this).addClass('active');
$('.thumbnail').removeClass('active');
});
```

Two issues:
1. when it slide down, it is not sliding smoothly. Is there any way to use CSS3 animation to make the details slide up and down smoothly? For example, the whole detail div should show all info at one go. Slidetoggle slide down giving details bit by bit in a sense.
2. Realized that details div will be outside the thumbnails. How to relate detail div to clicked thumbnails?

**Updated**
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fpx9gvzw/1/)

Tried data-rel to see if it show specific detail when clicking specific thumbnail but it seems not to work?

Comment: For the smoothness issue, try the `velocity` plugin (or similar). It converts `animate()` style commands (use `velocity()` instead) into CSS animation behind the scenes (much smoother). That usually means you have to replace all your `slideToggle` etc with the animate equivalent.

Comment: For the second issue, use `data-` attributes to mark what the associated element is (could use an id, a selector, or whatever you like).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - thanks for quick help. Regarding velocity - do you have any plugin to recommend? data-attributes - if I use it for thumbnail and detail it will know that they are related?

Comment: Th name of the plugin I used was, literally, `velocity` http://julian.com/research/velocity/ :) I will add an answer to cover my suggestions in more detail.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - thanks again and I have added in fiddle with data-rel but it is not working? Maybe I understand wrongly.

Comment: Updated to show example using a basic selector as the attribute, to match an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the smoothness issue, try the `velocity` plugin (or similar). It converts `animate()` style commands (use `velocity()` instead) into CSS animation behind the scenes (much smoother). That usually means you have to replace all your `slideToggle()` function etc with the `animate(...)` equivalent, then rename them to `velocity(...)`.

Velocity link: http://julian.com/research/velocity/

For the second issue, use `data-` attributes to mark what the associated element is (could use an id, a class selector, or whatever you like).

Your HTML is incomplete, but use it like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-rel="#details1">
```

and

```
<div class="details" id="details1">
    Thumbnail 1
</div>
```

and change the click handler to lookup the related element:

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function(e){
    var target = $(this).data('rel');
    var $target = $(target);

    // Close all but the new target and open it
    $('.details').not($target).slideUp();
    $(target).slideDown('slow');

    // Remove active from all active elements
    $('.thumbnail .active').removeClass('active');

    // Add active only to this element
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fpx9gvzw/3/

You can use an id selector with IDs on the target elements, a class selector with unique classes on the targets, or a `data-` attributes on the targets and match with a selector like `$([data-rel="..."])` but that is much slower (not that speed matters on this).

Note: I am not a huge fan of the "toggle" animation methods (except to toggle a current element), as the state can get messed up, hence using `not` and the `slideUp` and `slideDown` on appropriate elements.

Comment: thanks for your help. Checked velocity and it is a bit overwhelming but I will check on it in depth later.

Comment: @joe: The docs are a bit overwhelming, but it is as simple as including it and rename `animate` calls to `velocity`.

Comment: thanks alot. One last question - it doesn't need CSS3 to work together with?

Comment: It creates any required CSS *on the fly*. That will likely be CSS3. It says it will work on IE8 upwards. Otherwise it should fallback to normal `animate` on older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/fpx9gvzw/6/)

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function(e){
    var rel = $(this).data().rel;

    $('.details').stop().slideUp('slow');                       // all up!
    $('.details[data-rel='+rel+']').stop().slideToggle('slow'); // this toggle

    $('.thumbnail').removeClass('active'); // Remove from all
    $(this).addClass('active');            // Add to this
});
```

Comment: first thumbnail and last one don't slide down detail till click twice or thrice, it will slide. why?

Comment: @joe seems pretty obvious, if you remove that overlaying a elements (buttons or whatever they are) here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/fpx9gvzw/6/